# How can CodeMirror display an 'javascript object' string with object structure

Tags: object, codemirror

I start use [code mirror](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html), and i want to display an object with object structure.

I have a file with this content

```
{ property1: 'value', property2: { property3: 'value' }}
```

This is written in one line in .txt file.

Now i want to use code mirror so user can edit this file content.
I get the file content using HTTP call and after that i have this code

```
        var editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('reportEditor'), {
            mode: { name: "javascript", json: true },
            theme: "default",
            lineNumbers: true,
            readOnly: false,
            value: JSON.stringify(response.data),
        });
```

This works fine, i get the content but code mirror display it in one line.

How can force Code Mirror to display this value like an object structure like

```
 { 
      property1: 'value', 
      property2: { 
           property3: 'value' 
      }
 }
```

I found on this  [site](https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/)  a very good json prettifier

Answer (score 3):

The key was here `JSON.stringify(response.data, null, "\t")` now has JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the string into codemirror's editor, make sure you beautify your it for your preferred format.

eg. https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Also you can use the beautifier here 
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('reportEditor'), {
            mode: { name: "javascript", json: true },
            theme: "default",
            lineNumbers: true,
            readOnly: false,
            value: JSON.stringify(response.data,null,2),
        });
```

this works for me, setting replacer to null and indentation as 2 when changing the JSON to string.[image]

Comment: that did work, but I didnt get the collapse/expand buttons as pasted in your image. How to get that?